# What could be the error when we pass the invalid bucket name and bucket which is not present on s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was working on s3 i was creating a corner case when the user put the wrong bucket which is not present on the s3 but when I did the request call with an invalid bucket name I am still getting the error message as 'Bucket does not exist.

So I didn't get that like if we pass the correct format we should be getting the message as follow 'Bucket doesn't exist'.

But in case of incorrect form of bucket it should be giving the error message for invalid bucket name and error code according to that

Comment: Can you add an example of what you consider to be an invalid bucket name here? And which AWS Node.js SDK method are you using (add your code)?

Comment: Most of the List APIs do not validate bucket names, so if you hand them an invalid bucket name, they'll fail with the error you see.  Do you see any documentation that suggests otherwise?

Comment: So i am using copyObject here and as per the scenario the destination bucket name is wrong could be an invalid form also.

Comment: Well, it's certainly true that a bucket name that is somehow invalid (e.g. which has an unsupported character set) is also a bucket that does not exist. If S3 doesn't happen to validate the character set in this scenario then you either have to accept that fact or build a custom solution that gives you what you want.

Answer (score 2):

When you say invalid bucket-name that has to be dealt separately by your code. And you can use the below code to check if the bucket exist:

```
const checkBucketExists = async bucket => { 

  // here you can add the validation for bucketName
  // and based on the validation you can return the status code.
  const s3 = new AWS.S3();
  const options = {
    Bucket: bucket,
  };
  try {
    await s3.headBucket(options).promise();
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.statusCode === 404) {
      return false;
    }
    throw error;
  }
};
```